# How to use wkhtmltoimage with php

Tags: php, output, wkhtmltoimage

I want when I run the php file that is a picture taken from the site and will appear in the php file. The image should be saved with a random name. That I have not managed it because I do not know how to do it.

My actual code doesn't work too. How I can fix this?

```php
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];    // Website URL to Create Image
$name = $_GET['img'];   // Output Image Name
$command = "wkhtmltoimage --load-error-handling ignore";
$dir_img = "/var/www/vhosts/dl.andisblog.eu/httpdocs/screener/";     // Image files will be saved here
$ex_cmd = "$command $url " . $dir_img . $name;
$output = shell_exec($ex_cmd);
?>
```

---

Edit 1:

I have created a new php file.

```html
<?php

$url = str_replace('index.php','', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$url = str_replace($url,'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = explode('/',$url);
$name = array_shift($url);
$weburl = array_shift($url);

$command = "wkhtmltoimage --load-error-handling ignore";
$dir_img = "/var/www/vhosts/dl.andisblog.eu/andiundso.de/images";     // Image files will be saved here
$ex_cmd = "$command $weburl " . $dir_img . $name;
$output = shell_exec($ex_cmd);
echo "<img src=\"/images/$name\" >";  // comment this to disable image show on page

?>
```

and this .htaccess file

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /images/.+(gif|png|jpg)$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Now is the URL:
 http://domain.com/[imagename]/[site_url_without_http_prefix]

For example:
 http://andiundso.de/ribingtestzero.jpg/bing.com

But there gets no image?

Comment: Firstly does your server hav wkhtmltoimage available? - try running that on the command line/ssh.

Comment: It works with ssh (command line).  | wkhtmltoimage --no-images --load-error-handling ignore http://google.com goog.jpg

Comment: Your code is returning `404`. Check your `.htaccess`.

Comment: I see. But i don't know why..